# Django-forms validation problem at initialization

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a problem about validation of form fields in Django.

I have a `profile_edit` form it has a set of `clean` functions. Also, in order to control the current password, I need to pass current user's password to the form.

```
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("member_Email"),required = True)
currentPassword = forms.CharField(label=_("member_currentPassword"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
newPassword = forms.CharField(label=_("member_newPassword"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
newPasswordRe = forms.CharField(label=_("member_newPasswordRe"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
emailPreference = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_email_preference"), widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices = UserMailPreference.USER_MAIL_PREF,required = True)
gender = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_gender"), widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices = UserGender.USER_GENDER ,required = False)
birthYear = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_birthyear"),required = False)
education = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_education"),choices = UserEducation.USER_EDU, required = False)

def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(MemberSettings,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.fields["birthYear"].choices = birthYearList

def set_user(self, user):
    self.user = user

def clean_email(self):
    field_data = self.cleaned_data['email']

    if not field_data:
        return ''

    try:
        u = User.objects.get(email=field_data)
        if not u.id == self.user.id:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('err_already_registered'))
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    return field_data
```

By using the `set_user` method I can pass the current user to form however, when I write

```
form = MemberSettings(default_data)
form.set_user(u)
```

in my view, form tries to validate all the fields although I just try to initialize the form.
But if I do not set the user, form works normal.

What is the problem that I can't notice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer on: [Django form edit problem at intiliazation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400465/django-form-edit-problem-at-intiliazation)

It's the same issue. You need to use the initial argument when passing data to the form.