# Django form edit problem at intiliazation

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, initialization

I have a trouble with pre-population of the forms in Django. Because debuggin tool in Aptana doesn't work well, I couldn't detect the error. 
I think when I try `form = MemberSettings(default_data)` form tries to validate the data and it gives errors for invalid fields even in first load.

Could you help me to find out the problem ?

Thanks

**forms.py**

```
class MemberSettings(forms.Form):
email = forms.EmailField(label=_("member_Email"),required = True)
currentPassword = forms.CharField(label=_("member_currentPassword"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
newPassword = forms.CharField(label=_("member_newPassword"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
newPasswordRe = forms.CharField(label=_("member_newPasswordRe"),widget=forms.PasswordInput,required=False)
emailPreference = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_email_preference"), widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices = UserMailPreference.USER_MAIL_PREF,required = True)
gender = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_gender"), widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer),choices = UserGender.USER_GENDER ,required = False)
birthYear = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_birthyear"),required = False)
education = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("member_education"),choices = UserEducation.USER_EDU, required = False)

def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(MemberSettings,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    birthYearList = []
    for i in reversed(range (now.year-80,now.year-13)):
        birthYearList.append((i,str(i)))
    self.fields["birthYear"].choices = birthYearList

def clean_currentPassword(self):
    field_data = self.cleaned_data['currentPassword']

    if len(field_data) <= 0:
        return field_data

    if len(field_data.split(' ')) != 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_empty_char'))

    if len(field_data) > 32:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_maxChar'))

    if len(field_data) < 5:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_minChar'))

    return field_data

def clean_newPassword(self):
    field_data = self.cleaned_data['newPassword']

    if len(field_data) <= 0:
        return field_data

    if len(field_data.split(' ')) != 1:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_empty_char'))

    if len(field_data) > 32:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_maxChar'))

    if len(field_data) < 5:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('member_err_password_minChar'))

    return field_data
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def settings_edit(request):
u = request.user
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MemberSettings(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        return redirect('/member/settings_edit/')
    else:
        return render_response(request, 'member/settings_edit.html', {'form': form})
else:
    default_data = {
            'email': u.email,
            'gender': u.get_profile().gender,
            'education': u.get_profile().education,
            'birthYear': u.get_profile().birthyear,
            'emailPreference': u.get_profile().mail_preference,
            }
    form = MemberSettings(default_data)
    return render_response(request, 'user/settings_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the initial argument when constructing your form instance in the view:

```
form = MemberSettings(initial=default_data)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/ for more information. Hope that helps you out.